# получить разницу между двумя датами в Moment и Corezoid

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как получить разницу между датами, постоянно выдает ошибку: endTime.diff is not a function

```
require("libs/moment.js");
moment.locale('ru');

var startTime = moment(data.time.date_start).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
var endTime = moment(data.result.task.deadline).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
    

var duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
var hours = duration.asHours();
data.duration = hours;
```

Comment: `moment.duration(moment(data.result.task.deadline,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm').diff(moment(data.time.date_start,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')))` а так?

Comment: нет, я уже как только не пробовал

Comment: `console.log(startTime.isValid(), endTime.isValid());` что выдаёт?

Answer (score 1):

Считает в каризойде:

```
var a = moment(data.time.date_start);`
var b = moment(data.result.task.deadline);
data.difference = b.diff(a, 'hours');
```